# How to print certain indexes based off of certain check boxes being checked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Below I have an array and in my design I have a check list box with 10 options. For example, if boxes 1 and 2 were checked, I would only want to print Indexes 0 and 1 ONLY. I have a button that prints all of the array members (included below) and that is what I want to make print only selected items. I have tried using a switch but that file had gotten corrupted and I am lost. Thank you. (Language is VB)

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles 
btn1.Click

    Dim strDecimal(9) As String

            strDecimal(0) = FormatPercent(0.0146175)
            strDecimal(1) = FormatPercent(0.0345324585)
            strDecimal(2) = FormatPercent(0.09324543575)
            strDecimal(3) = FormatPercent(0.07346475)
            strDecimal(4) = FormatPercent(0.0772346615)
            strDecimal(5) = FormatPercent(0.42234234654)
            strDecimal(6) = FormatPercent(0.6246264664)
            strDecimal(7) = FormatPercent(0.4524642234)
            strDecimal(8) = FormatPercent(0.6876543534)
            strDecimal(9) = FormatPercent(0.6876543534)

    For num As Integer = 0 To strDecimal.Length - 1
        listArrays.Items.Add(strDecimal(num))
    Next
 End Sub

Private Sub clearList()
    listArrays.Items.Clear()
  End Sub

  Private Sub btn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles btn2.Click
    clearList()
  End Sub
```

Comment: there is no code there to output the arrays anywhere.  show your "switch" (Called a CASE Statement, if thats what you meant) to send to file or whereever.  Hard to help with code we cant see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a CheckedListBox and want to know which items are Checked:

```
Private Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    For Each itm As String In listArrays.CheckedItems
        Debug.Print(itm)
    Next
End Sub
```